# Problem regarding tensorflow in Jetson nano(ubuntu)

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia-jetson-nano

Okay... So I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort.git) repo on my jetson nano 2gb...

I followed [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html) official documentation for installation for tensorflow on jetson nano, while I followed https://www.tensorflow.org/install, this official documentation to run tensorflow on windows..

So after setting the dependencies on windows...the started to run smoothly with no problem.

But after setting the dependencies on jetson nano... the code showed this error..

```
python3 object_tracker.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-416 --model yolov4 --video 0 --tiny --info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_tracker.py", line 238, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_tracker.py", line 73, in main
    saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(FLAGS.weights, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 603, in load
    return load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 633, in load_internal
    ckpt_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 131, in __init__
    self._restore_checkpoint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 330, in _restore_checkpoint
    load_status = saver.restore(variables_path, self._checkpoint_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py", line 1320, in restore
    checkpoint=checkpoint, proto_id=0).restore(self._graph_view.root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 209, in restore
    restore_ops = trackable._restore_from_checkpoint_position(self)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 914, in _restore_from_checkpoint_position
    tensor_saveables, python_saveables))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py", line 297, in restore_saveables
    validated_saveables).restore(self.save_path_tensor, self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py", line 340, in restore
    restore_ops = restore_fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py", line 316, in restore_fn
    restore_ops.update(saver.restore(file_prefix, options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py", line 111, in restore
    restored_tensors, restored_shapes=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/saveable_object_util.py", line 125, in restore
    restored_tensor = array_ops.identity(restored_tensor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 287, in identity
    ret = gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3992, in identity
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6843, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run Identity: Dst tensor is not initialized. [Op:Identity]
```

So I thought it could be a memory issue..so I ran `tegrastats` to check the status of the RAM and the SWAP memory... Here is what tegrastats logged..

```
RAM 453/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@31C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39C thermal@30.75C
RAM 453/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@31C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39C thermal@30.75C
RAM 453/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@31C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39C thermal@30.75C
RAM 466/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [6%@1224,39%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39.5C thermal@31.25C
RAM 476/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [10%@1224,33%@1224,1%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39C thermal@30.75C
RAM 480/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [26%@1224,11%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@31C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39C thermal@30.75C
RAM 498/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [8%@1479,33%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@31C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39.5C thermal@30.75C
RAM 512/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [31%@1479,43%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39.5C thermal@30.75C
RAM 525/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [11%@1479,67%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39C thermal@31.5C
RAM 539/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 3MB) CPU [8%@1479,47%@1479,11%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@31C
RAM 552/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [11%@1224,53%@1224,1%@1224,2%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@28.5C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@39.5C thermal@31.25C
RAM 570/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [8%@1479,67%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@31.25C
RAM 583/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [4%@1479,70%@1479,7%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@31.5C
RAM 593/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [11%@1479,48%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@31.25C
RAM 601/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [8%@1224,32%@1224,14%@1224,18%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@39.5C thermal@31.5C
RAM 607/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [10%@1224,5%@1224,5%@1224,1%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@31.5C
RAM 626/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [21%@1224,8%@1224,10%@1224,3%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 2% PLL@29C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@28.5C AO@39.5C thermal@31C
RAM 670/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [12%@1479,5%@1479,21%@1479,6%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 27% PLL@29C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@29C AO@39.5C thermal@30.25C
RAM 741/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [20%@1479,5%@1479,20%@1479,14%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@29C AO@39.5C thermal@30.25C
RAM 820/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [23%@1479,27%@1479,20%@1479,15%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 52% PLL@29C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@28.5C AO@40C thermal@30.75C
RAM 920/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [17%@1479,7%@1479,45%@1479,20%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 1% PLL@29C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@29C AO@39.5C thermal@30.5C
RAM 1020/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [18%@1224,6%@1224,70%@1224,9%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@29.5C AO@39.5C thermal@30.75C
RAM 1036/1980MB (lfb 22x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [11%@1479,20%@1479,29%@1479,10%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@31.5C
RAM 1093/1980MB (lfb 12x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [72%@1479,0%@1479,1%@1479,3%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@30.25C
RAM 1106/1980MB (lfb 8x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [96%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@31.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@30.25C
RAM 1116/1980MB (lfb 6x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@40C thermal@31.25C
RAM 1122/1980MB (lfb 4x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@31.5C
RAM 1131/1980MB (lfb 1x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [69%@1479,31%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@39.5C thermal@31.75C
RAM 1137/1980MB (lfb 1x2MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@31.75C
RAM 1147/1980MB (lfb 12x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1152/1980MB (lfb 9x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@31.75C
RAM 1161/1980MB (lfb 4x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@39.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1171/1980MB (lfb 19x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1178/1980MB (lfb 10x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1184/1980MB (lfb 3x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@39.5C thermal@32C
RAM 1189/1980MB (lfb 3x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,3%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32C
RAM 1204/1980MB (lfb 3x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [2%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1204/1980MB (lfb 3x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@31.75C
RAM 1216/1980MB (lfb 19x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@39.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1223/1980MB (lfb 19x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1218/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [56%@1479,41%@1479,3%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32C
RAM 1221/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1224/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,98%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1229/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1223/1980MB (lfb 17x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1230/1980MB (lfb 17x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@31.75C
RAM 1230/1980MB (lfb 17x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1225/1980MB (lfb 16x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1234/1980MB (lfb 13x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1230/1980MB (lfb 15x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1225/1980MB (lfb 16x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1226/1980MB (lfb 16x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1229/1980MB (lfb 16x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1232/1980MB (lfb 16x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1235/1980MB (lfb 13x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40.5C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1229/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1230/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@31.75C
RAM 1231/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40.5C thermal@31.75C
RAM 1233/1980MB (lfb 6x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1236/1980MB (lfb 3x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1239/1980MB (lfb 14x256kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1236/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1238/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1246/1980MB (lfb 1x2MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1246/1980MB (lfb 1x2MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1248/1980MB (lfb 1x2MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40.5C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1248/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [2%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1253/1980MB (lfb 3x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1244/1980MB (lfb 1x2MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,2%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1247/1980MB (lfb 3x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1247/1980MB (lfb 3x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@40C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1249/1980MB (lfb 2x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1254/1980MB (lfb 4x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@33C
RAM 1246/1980MB (lfb 1x2MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,1%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1251/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1256/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1253/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,2%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1254/1980MB (lfb 2x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@40.5C thermal@33C
RAM 1256/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1261/1980MB (lfb 2x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1265/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,2%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1269/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@33C
RAM 1264/1980MB (lfb 2x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,1%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@33C
RAM 1272/1980MB (lfb 2x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1272/1980MB (lfb 2x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1277/1980MB (lfb 2x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [2%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1279/1980MB (lfb 2x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,1%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1280/1980MB (lfb 2x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1283/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,1%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1283/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1291/1980MB (lfb 2x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1298/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,1%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1296/1980MB (lfb 1x2MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479,1%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33.25C
RAM 1299/1980MB (lfb 1x2MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [3%@1224,84%@1224,1%@1224,1%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 2% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@30C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1302/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [4%@1479,6%@1479,85%@1479,7%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@31.75C
RAM 1306/1980MB (lfb 1x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,0%@1479,100%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1307/1980MB (lfb 5x1MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [2%@1479,0%@1479,100%@1479,5%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@34C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@33C
RAM 1319/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [31%@1224,29%@1224,25%@1224,3%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [7%@1224,5%@1224,0%@1224,5%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1337/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@29.5C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@31.5C AO@41C thermal@32C
RAM 1338/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [69%@1479,2%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1338/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1338/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 1338/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [100%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1338/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [95%@1479,4%@1479,0%@1479,1%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.5C
RAM 1338/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,100%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1338/1980MB (lfb 1x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,100%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1320/1980MB (lfb 7x512kB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1479,0%@1479,0%@1479,100%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 1090/1980MB (lfb 7x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,100%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30.5C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32.5C AO@41C thermal@32.75C
RAM 342/1980MB (lfb 18x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [6%@1479,9%@1479,17%@1479,1%@1479] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33.5C PMIC@100C GPU@30.5C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 342/1980MB (lfb 18x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 342/1980MB (lfb 18x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@40.5C thermal@32.25C
RAM 342/1980MB (lfb 18x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@32.5C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
RAM 342/1980MB (lfb 18x4MB) SWAP 121/11230MB (cached 7MB) CPU [1%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224,0%@1224] EMC_FREQ 0% GR3D_FREQ 0% PLL@30C CPU@33C PMIC@100C GPU@32C AO@41C thermal@32.25C
```

I can't understand what could be the possible cause of this..

Things I have tried:

1. Clone a different repo for object detection, same result
2. Changed my tensorflow version to 2.3.0 as requirement for the code..no change
3. Trained the model and ran it through tensorRT...same result

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks..

EDIT: Title and tag change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line at the starting of the object_tracker.py file and before importing tensorflow:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'
```

I hope this solves the error for anyone who faces this error..